# How to use file_get_contents in storage path using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm storing an image into my `app\avatars` and then i would like to use the function `file_get_contents`.

My controller look like this:

```
public function store()
{

    $file = request()->file('avatar');

    $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();

    $fullname = request('familyname') . '_' . request('name') . '.' . $ext;

    $file->storeAs('avatars', $fullname);

    $path = storage_path("\app\avatars\\") . $fullname;

    dd(file_get_contents($path));


    return back();

}
```

unfortunately I'm getting:

```
ûeiuu§┬Ù9/\x1C<ÆS,ìFCÙÙÙÃÜà▒Í\x03\x00Ç╗┴<¤\x1DÃÐ■■¥÷¸¸/T§©p­0ò\fÎuÁÁÁul¥Ã4\x19\x01\x00\x00wK\x18åZ]]¢ðs■ÊS-¥´Ù├ç\x0F\n
éá+x░ã\x03\x00Ç╗#╣t┬▓,ÝýýÞ­­­▄[k/\x1D<ÄÄÄ┤ÀÀGùR\x00\x00¯░õ‗\tÃqÈh4Ô\x16\x1AÎ\x1A<ÂÂÂÔ-┤\x00\x00Ó¯2U\x0F¾¾ÍÍû:Ø╬╣Ní┐TZ­}_╗╗╗¶ý\x00\x00`╚XûÑr╣¼JÑ\x12w/?K\x16©p­p\ ▶
\x12þÜj▒,K═fS§zØO\e\x00Ç!ù\f\x17ÄÒ¿V½ÚÞÞHÂmÃK0z\x03╚╣ªZ╠┬Êv╗═Ü\x0E\x00\x00ðÁ¶óËÚ¿V½u\x05ÄÌ].þÌıÊh4ÈjÁÞ¦\x01\x00\x00íú+`°¥»¢¢=àaxbN8W­\x08├Pççç|Ê\x00\x00áo\x10®V ▶
█V¡Vï¹y¶\v\x1Fþ\x0E\x1EGGG|▓\x00\x00á»v╗¡úúú\x13¤r;Î«\x16│¥âàÑ\x00\x00á_V\x08├PòJÕ─>_gJ\x10fGK¡Vï¸þ\x02\x00\x00¶2╦2.Á½┼öKÛ§║┬0õS\x05\x00\x00}┘Â¡z¢~Ô\f╔ÖâçY▀\x11 ▶
\r\n
<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n
\r\n
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>\r\n
\r\n
</title></head>\r\n
<body>\r\n
    <form method="post" action="./CCMitarbeiterFoto.aspx?PersonalNr=1078" id="form1">\r\n
<div class="aspNetHidden">\r\n
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="9zVUfo54MulsAKKPPJ1Fa/uA+ZFrKTIMV4BTUC9XFiuaf68xeY7nuOELPtxrcdAjY37Aes+GE/DYDH6TQHs0AVHJ8B+z/Ht8 ▶
</div>\r\n
\r\n
<div class="aspNetHidden">\r\n
\r\n
\t<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="4673F310" />\r\n
</div>\r\n
        <div>\r\n
        </div>\r\n
    </form>\r\n
</body>\r\n
</html>\r\n
```

I don't understand why do i get also a html tags... This should reads my file into a string.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the file does not contain any html?

Comment: I'm saving a .jpeg

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app/avatars/` ? Slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: I'm getting the same result with slashes

Comment: are you sure of your $path value and the file is saved correctly?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SOD6x. I'm storing it in app/avatars. The helper function  point to the storage path. If i `dd($path)`. I get this path: `"C:\xampp\htdocs\ccup\storage\app\avatars\Doe_John.jpeg"`